# How can I get impl Trait to use the appropriate lifetime for a mutable reference to a value with another lifetime in it?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a struct with a lifetime:

```
struct HasLifetime<'a>( /* ... */ );
```

There is there is an implementation of the trait `Foo`:

```
impl<'a, 'b: 'a> Foo for &'a mut HasLifetime<'b> { }
```

I want to implement the following function:

```
fn bar_to_foo<'a, 'b: 'a>(bar: &'a mut Lifetime<'b>) -> impl Foo {
    bar
}
```

This won't compile because the returned `impl` is only valid for `'a`. However, specifying `impl Foo + 'a` results in:

```
error[E0909]: hidden type for `impl Trait` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
 --> src/main.rs:7:60
  |
7 | fn bar_to_foo<'a, 'b: 'a>(bar: &'a mut HasLifetime<'b>) -> impl Trait + 'a {
  |                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: hidden type `&'a mut HasLifetime<'b>` captures the lifetime 'b as defined on the function body at 7:1
 --> src/main.rs:7:1
  |
7 | fn bar_to_foo<'a, 'b: 'a>(bar: &'a mut HasLifetime<'b>) -> impl Trait + 'a {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The seemingly equivalent function with a boxed trait object compiles:

```
fn bar_to_foo<'a, 'b: 'a>(bar: &'a mut Lifetime<'b>) -> Box<Foo + 'a> {
    Box::new(bar)
}
```

How can I define `bar_to_foo` with `impl Trait`?

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b8f293acecf4b7e1f3c5963f15c36b1e&version=stable&mode=debug)

Comment: This *might* be a bug. If it is, [#51069](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51069) might be related.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to indicate that the returned value is built upon multiple lifetimes. However, you can't use multiple lifetime bounds with `impl Trait`, and attempting to do so [doesn't have a useful error message](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49431).

There's [a trick you can use](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34511#issuecomment-373423999) that involves creating a dummy trait that has a lifetime parameter:

```
trait Captures<'a> {}
impl<'a, T: ?Sized> Captures<'a> for T {}

fn bar_to_foo<'a, 'b: 'a>(bar: &'a mut HasLifetime<'b>) -> impl Trait + Captures<'b> + 'a {
    bar
}
```

Thankfully, this [only occurs when the "hidden" lifetime is invariant](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34511#issuecomment-373455139), which occurs because the reference is mutable.