# impl Iterator failing for iterator with multiple lifetime parameters

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I've got code that looks (a little) like this:

```
struct OutputIterator<'r, 'i: 'r> {
    input_handler: &'r mut InputHandler<'i>
}

impl<'r, 'i> Iterator for OutputIterator<'r, 'i> {
    type Item = i32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.input_handler.inputs.next().map(|x| x * 2)
    }
}

struct InputHandler<'a> {
    inputs: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = i32> + 'a>
}

impl<'a> InputHandler<'a> {
    fn outputs<'b>(&'b mut self) -> OutputIterator<'b, 'a> {
        OutputIterator { input_handler: self }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut input_handler = InputHandler {
        inputs: Box::new(vec![1,2,3,4,5].into_iter())
    };
    for output in input_handler.outputs() {
        println!("{}", output);
    }
}
```

Basically, the user can supply an iterator of inputs, and then get an iterator of outputs (in my real code the connection between inputs and outputs is much more complex involving a bunch of internal state. Multiple inputs might go towards one output or vice-versa).

This works, but I would like to change it use `impl Iterator` both to hide the `OutputIterator` type and to allow for easier swapping out of the return type in testing with a fake. My best attempt at that changes the InputHandler impl like so:

```
impl<'a> InputHandler<'a> {
    fn outputs<'b>(&'b mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> + 'b {
        OutputIterator { input_handler: self }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, that gets me: `` error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Trait` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds ``

Is there a way to make this work? It's important for the interface that `InputHandler` take an iterator with some lifetime, and that obviously has to be passed on to the `OutputIterator` somehow, but I'd really like to abstract those details away from the caller. In principle, the caller should only have to worry about making sure that the inputs `Iterator` and `InputHandler` outlive the `OutputIterator` so I think the logical lifetime bound on the `OutputIterator` here is the smaller of those two? Any clarity on why this error is happening or how to fix it would be great!

In case it helps, here's a [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dfb7cada28d3d9c9ab42f5a0b5e25359) with the code in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a workaround from https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34511#issuecomment-373423999, via https://stackoverflow.com/a/50548538/1757964:

```
trait Captures<'a> {}
impl<'a, T: ?Sized> Captures<'a> for T {}

impl<'a> InputHandler<'a> {
    fn outputs<'b>(&'b mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> + Captures<'a> + 'b {
        OutputIterator { input_handler: self }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! It's a little ugly of course, but it works! Do you have a sense if this is a necessary feature of how the lifetime system works, vs. being a rough edge they might fix some day?