# Lifetime issue with a mutable reference to a struct with a lifetime specifier and impl trait

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, lifetime

I'm trying to pass around a mutable reference to a `Container` struct which holds references with a lifetime of `'a`. Since the mutable reference often doesn't live as long as the container itself which might e.g. have a lifetime of `'static` in my example, I tried giving it its own lifetime of `'b`.
I tried specifying that `'a` can outlive `'b` with the `'a: 'b` syntax. However, the resulting code doesn't compile with a cryptic error message.

What went wrong here? How could I fix it?

Here's my minimum working example:

```rust
// Example container with a lifetime
struct Container<'a> {
    sequence: &'a [usize],
}

impl<'a> Container<'a> {
    // Returns an Iterator which holds a reference to the container to iterate over
    fn get_iterator(&mut self) -> ContainerIterator<'a, '_> {
        ContainerIterator {
            container: self,
            index: 0,
        }
    }
}

// Iterator which holds a reference to the Container where 'b may outlive 'a
struct ContainerIterator<'a, 'b>
where
    'b: 'a,
{
    container: &'a mut Container<'b>,
    index: usize,
}

// Simple iterator implementation as an example
impl<'a, 'b> Iterator for ContainerIterator<'a, 'b> {
    type Item = usize;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<usize> {
        if self.index >= self.container.sequence.len() {
            None
        } else {
            Some(self.container.sequence[self.index])
        }
    }
}
impl<'a, 'b> ExactSizeIterator for ContainerIterator<'a, 'b> {}

// This is the function where things go wrong - it should return an iterator which maps the outputs of the `ContainerIterator`
fn get_iterator<'a, 'b: 'a>(
    container: &'a mut Container<'b>,
) -> impl ExactSizeIterator<Item = usize> + 'a {
    container.get_iterator().map(|index| index * 2)
}

fn main() {
    // Container with 'static data and some example code
    let mut container = Container {
        sequence: &[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    };
    let output: Vec<_> = get_iterator(&mut container).collect();
    dbg! {output};
}
```

This is the resulting compiler error which I don't know how to interpret or resolve:

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
  --> src/main.rs:42:15
   |
40 |     container: &'a mut Container<'b>,
   |                ---------------------
   |                |
   |                these two types are declared with different lifetimes...
41 | ) -> impl ExactSizeIterator<Item = usize> + 'a {
42 |     container.get_iterator().map(|index| index * 2)
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...but data from `container` flows into `container` here
```

Comment: Unrelated things: your `index` never increments. I don't think you should implement `ExactSizeIterator` because you don't implement `size_hint`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How can I get impl Trait to use the appropriate lifetime for a mutable reference to a value with another lifetime in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50547766/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c51df082ad31be4e60f8a8bb6d73342a). I also had to swap the lifetimes (`fn get_iterator(&mut self) -> ContainerIterator<'_, 'a>`) as they were backwards.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks, that does indeed answer it. I don't think I would've ever found that question you linked otherwise. You were also right with the example iterator not being implemented correctly which I didn't notice since the main issue here was that it didn't compile in the first place. I tried to keep it as close as possible to my actual code as possible while removing everything that's unnecessary and removed a bit too much. Should I delete this question now?

Comment: *Should I delete this question* — nope! Duplicates exist for this very reason: "I don't think I would've ever found that question you linked otherwise". Duplicates remain as signposts to help people who search using the same terms you used.