# Async fn reports "hidden type for `impl Trait` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds"

Tags: rust

If I remove the `'static` lifetime of the final argument, the program compiles. If I add it back, it fails. To me, it seems both should be valid. [Minimal reproduction](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c4b48a9611f760226b37832138691e1d):

```rust
use std::io;

struct Foo {
    user: String,
    pass: String,
}

impl Foo {
    async fn not_works(
        &mut self,
        user: &str,
        pass: &str,
        app_name: &'static str,
    ) -> io::Result<()> {
        self.user = user.to_string() + app_name;
        self.pass = pass.to_string();

        self.do_stuff().await
    }

    async fn works(&mut self, user: &str, pass: &str, app_name: &str) -> io::Result<()> {
        self.user = user.to_string() + app_name;
        self.pass = pass.to_string();

        self.do_stuff().await
    }

    async fn do_stuff(&self) -> io::Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo {
        user: "".to_string(),
        pass: "".to_string(),
    };

    foo.not_works("test", "password", "foobar").await.unwrap();
}
```

```
error[E0700]: hidden type for `impl Trait` captures lifetime that does not appear in bounds
  --> src/main.rs:14:10
   |
14 |     ) -> io::Result<()> {
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: hidden type `impl Future` captures lifetime smaller than the function body
  --> src/main.rs:14:10
   |
14 |     ) -> io::Result<()> {
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It's much more likely the bug is in my understanding and not the compiler though. What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure if it is a bug or type inference works this way but if you explicitly state lifetime parameters instead of using anonymous it works. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2a81e244c9a8614a5ba0b5f2e769da97)

Comment: And if you make them unique lifetime parameters (which I think is equivalent to leaving them out) it also fails: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ae398bea65e92c7002bc8590c56eb0ea)

Comment: Looks like this is a bug, there is even crate out there to fix: https://crates.io/crates/fix-hidden-lifetime-bug, please check the external post links in the details section, it might be useful

Comment: I opened an issue here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87632

Comment: [How can I get impl Trait to use the appropriate lifetime for a mutable reference to a value with another lifetime in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50547766/155423)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [a limitation of the `async fn` implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63033#issuecomment-521234696). Basically, it tries to unify all lifetimes to be the same, and in this case they can't be all `'static`.

This works:

```rust
fn workaround<'a>(
    &'a mut self,
    user: &'a str,
    pass: &'a str,
    app_name: &'static str,
) -> impl Future<Output = io::Result<()>> + 'a {
    async move {
        self.user = user.to_string() + app_name;
        self.pass = pass.to_string();

        self.do_stuff().await
    }
}
```